# Binding Complex Types in MVC5

Tags: binding, asp.net-mvc-5, radio-button, complextype

I'm a newbie developer trying to develope a web application with asp .net mvc 5 for personel usage. The website kind of a quiz maker that I can insert Russian words with meanings and prepare a quiz by using these words.

When I trying to code the quiz page and post the data the the action method I faced some problem that I couldn't get around. I iterated through the Model, read the data and wrote them to the page. Now, what I want to do is, when I post the form, I want to get each question string and selected answer (maybe in this format: imgur.com/QETnafx). Therefore, I can easily check the answer string whether it is true or not.

I checked the following tutorials out:
Model Binding To A List by **Phil Haack** and ASP.NET Wire Format for Model Binding to Arrays, Lists, Collections, Dictionaries by **Scott Hanselman**

I hope I explained the situation clearly. If you need more information I can happily provide.

**ViewModel**

```
public class QuizInitializationModel
{
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionString
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string WordString { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public QuestionString QuestionString { get; set; }
    public List<AnswerItem> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class AnswerItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string WordString { get; set; }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Begin", "Quiz", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label(Model.Questions[i].QuestionString.WordString)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @for (int item = 0; item < Model.Questions[0].Answers.Count; item++)
                        {
                            @Html.Label(Model.Questions[i].Answers[item].WordString)@:&nbsp;
                            @Html.RadioButton("array" + "[" + @i + "]" + "." + Model.Questions[i].QuestionString.WordString, Model.Questions[i].Answers[item].Id)<br />
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary" />
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<form action="/Admin/Quiz/Begin" method="post">
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="">вулкан</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="trade">trade</label>&nbsp;
            <input id="array_0________" name="array[0].вулкан" type="radio" value="18" /><br />
            <label for="volcano">volcano</label>&nbsp;
            <input id="array_0________" name="array[0].вулкан" type="radio" value="24" /><br />
            <label for="talk__conversation">talk, conversation</label>&nbsp;
            <input id="array_0________" name="array[0].вулкан" type="radio" value="15" /><br />
            <label for="time">time</label>&nbsp;
            <input id="array_0________" name="array[0].вулкан" type="radio" value="13" /><br />
            <label for="income">income</label>&nbsp;
            <input id="array_0________" name="array[0].вулкан" type="radio" value="21" /><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="">мама</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="universe">universe</label>&nbsp;
            <input id="array_1______" name="array[1].мама" type="radio" value="25" /><br />
            <label for="peace">peace</label>&nbsp;
            <input id="array_1______" name="array[1].мама" type="radio" value="2" /><br />
            <label for="value">value</label>&nbsp;
            <input id="array_1______" name="array[1].мама" type="radio" value="20" /><br />
            <label for="mom__mama">mom, mama</label>&nbsp;
            <input id="array_1______" name="array[1].мама" type="radio" value="17" /><br />
            <label for="industry">industry</label>&nbsp;
            <input id="array_1______" name="array[1].мама" type="radio" value="19" /><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And how can i fix the ids of the labels like "array_1______" ? 
They appeared when I added this code **"array" + "[" + @i + "]" + "."** to the RadioButton control for the purpose of assign an index for each answer.

Comment: The `id` attribute is not the issue. Its the `name` attribute which posts back, and currently your names have no relationship to a model property so wont bind.

Comment: And FYI, the html helpers replace the `[`, `.` and `]` characters and invalid characters with underscores

Comment: What is your post method signature? Why do you not have a model property that you can bind to? And you don't need to worry about the `id` - its of no consequence

Comment: It's (QuizInitializationModel[] array).

Comment: Your view is not going to post back to that as I noted in my first comment. `QuizInitializationModel` does not contain a property named `array`! You need a property to bind to. I'll post an answer shortly, but I'm unsure of your comment _check the answer string whether it is true or not_. Do you have a property indicating if an answer is correct or not?

Comment: Thank you for your interesting. For me, It's kind of hard to understand the concepts. I think i need to study more on model & model binding topic. There is nothing except public List<Question> Questions { get; set; } in the view model. If i can get selected answer's string and id, I can compare the string with the data I get from the database via the id and say that If this string equals the string that comes from the database, its true otherwise it's not. Maybe it is a poor approach but... Whatever. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html helpers replace invalid characters with an underscore (a period is actually not invalid, but would cause problems with jquery so its also replaced an underscore). However `id` attribute is not the problem, although you are generating duplicates which is invalid html.

Your manually generating the `name` attribute for the radio buttons which have no relationship to any property in your model so wont be bound when you post back. Your model needs to include a property you can bind the selected answer to. Modify the `Question` model to

```
public class Question
{
  public QuestionString QuestionString { get; set; }
  public List<AnswerItem> Answers { get; set; }
  public int SelectedAnswer { get; set; } // add this
}
```

and modify the view to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) // note parameter not necessary if your posting to the same controller/action
{
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++)
  {
    ...
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Questions[i].QuestionString.Id)
    <h2>@Model.Questions[i].QuestionString.WordString)</h2>
    ...
    @foreach(var answer in Model.Questions[i].Answers)
    {
      var id = string.Format("{0}-{1}", @i, answer.Id);
      @Html.Label(id, answer.WordString)
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Questions[i].SelectedAnswer, answer.ID, new { id = id })
    }
    ....
  }
  <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

The radio buttons are now bound to the `SelectedAnswer` property and when you post back, the value will be the ID of the selected `AnswerItem`

Note also:

1. A hidden input has been added for the ID of the question so the
   question can be identified on post back
2. The question text is in a heading tag (could be another tag), but a
   label is not appropriate - a label is an element associated with a
   control (for setting focus to the control) but you don't have an
   associated control
3. A unique id is created in the `foreach` loop so you can give each
   radio button a unique id (so the html is valid) and associate the
   label (the answer text) with the button